# How to populate a GridView column with a button

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have the following `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDispMsg" ClientIDMode="Static" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Delete Message" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" DataField="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Width="13%" DataField="Created" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" HeaderStyle-Width="45%" DataField="Message" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Active" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" DataField="Active" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Created By" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" DataField="CreatedBy" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It is populated from a SQL table which is executed from code-behind. The only column which is not populated is the `Delete Message` column.

How can I add a button for each row in the `Delete Message` column which takes the argument for the `ID` datafield?

Comment: Where do I add that?

Comment: instead of the delete message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDeleted="NewEvent"
```

and handle the  NewEvent in CodeBehind

or

add a `<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="delete" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete"/>` instead of a BoundField

or

add

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="lbiDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate> 
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="lbiDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="lbiDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
    </FooterTemplate>                  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

where you have most abilities to configure this column in every state

Comment: But the HeaderText will be missing?

Comment: I need multiple DELETE button or can I just have one? :/

Comment: you can have as many as you want. just add multiple ButtonField oder TemplateFields

Comment: So instead of the BoundField, I should just add the <asp:TemplateField>?

Comment: add multiple ButtonField  or multiple TemplateFields - depens on which approach fits better to your needs. TemplateFields gives you more flexibility, ButtonField makes the code better to read